# problems when receiving data from jframe

Tags: java

I've been trying to add values to a list inside a class from a separated jFrame. I tested and know that the information is sending correctly and the function to receive this information is also receiving it correctly. The problem is that Im not sure if the information is being added into the list, because when i try to print it, nothing happens.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Conta {
    private int NumConta;
    private String Nome;
    private String RG;
    private String CPF;
    private double Saldo;
    private String Password;
    ArrayList<Conta> ListaUser;


    public Conta(){
        ListaUser = new ArrayList();
    }

    public Conta(int NumConta, String Nome, String RG, String CPF, double Saldo, String Password) {
        this.NumConta = NumConta;
        this.Nome = Nome;
        this.RG = RG;
        this.CPF = CPF;
        this.Saldo = Saldo;
        this.Password = Password;
        ListaUser = new ArrayList();
    }

    public int getNumConta() {
        return NumConta;
    }

    public void setNumConta(int NumConta) {
        this.NumConta = NumConta;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String Nome) {
        this.Nome = Nome;
    }

    public String getRG() {
        return RG;
    }

    public void setRG(String RG) {
        this.RG = RG;
    }

    public String getCPF() {
        return CPF;
    }

    public void setCPF(String CPF) {
        this.CPF = CPF;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return Saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double Saldo) {
        this.Saldo = Saldo;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String Password) {
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public ArrayList<Conta> getListaUser() {
        return ListaUser;
    }

    public void setListaUser(ArrayList<Conta> ListaUser) {
        this.ListaUser = ListaUser;
    }
    public void AddFunc(Conta C){
        ListaUser.add(C);
    }

}
```

This is the class which receives information

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cadastrar extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Cadastrar() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanelinicio = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextFieldnomecadastro = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextFieldRG = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextFieldCPF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextFieldpasswordcadastro = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButtonconfirmarcadastro = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonvoltarCadastrar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanelinicio.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 153, 255));

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel1.setText("RG:");

        jLabel2.setText("CPF:");

        jLabel3.setText("Nome:");

        jLabel4.setText("Password:");

        jButtonconfirmarcadastro.setText("Confirmar");
        jButtonconfirmarcadastro.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonconfirmarcadastroActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButtonvoltarCadastrar.setText("Voltar");
        jButtonvoltarCadastrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonvoltarCadastrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldpasswordcadastro, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldCPF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldRG, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldnomecadastro, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButtonconfirmarcadastro, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButtonvoltarCadastrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(173, 173, 173))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldnomecadastro, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldRG, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldCPF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldpasswordcadastro, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                .addComponent(jButtonconfirmarcadastro)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButtonvoltarCadastrar)
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelinicioLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelinicio);
        jPanelinicio.setLayout(jPanelinicioLayout);
        jPanelinicioLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelinicioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanelinicioLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelinicioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanelinicioLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanelinicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanelinicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonvoltarCadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
        Principal principal = new Principal();
        principal.setVisible(true);           
        dispose();
    }                                                      

    private void jButtonconfirmarcadastroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
        Random random = new Random();
        int numero = random.nextInt(9999999);
        Conta C = new Conta(numero,jTextFieldnomecadastro.getText(),jTextFieldRG.getText(),jTextFieldCPF.getText(),0,jTextFieldpasswordcadastro.getText());
        C.AddFunc(C);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conta criada com sucesso!\n"+"Numero da conta: "+numero);
        Principal p = new Principal();
        p.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastrar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastrar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastrar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastrar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Cadastrar().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonconfirmarcadastro;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonvoltarCadastrar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelinicio;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldCPF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldRG;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldnomecadastro;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldpasswordcadastro;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This jFrame sends the information.

How can I make the list receive information and how can I see all the information added?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You create new `Conta` object each time with new list, and add this newly created object to that new list.   Most likely, you should make your list static - then it'll be able to store all instances of `Conta` class.

Comment: @AlexRudenko, so do i just do this static ArrayList<Conta> ListaUser; when creating the list?

Comment: Should a `Conta` really be the thing that contains a List of Conta? Question yourself: Does each Conta [have-a](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.bg.doc/topics/c_is_a_has_a.html) Conta list?  In my opinion storing a list of Accounts in an Account is probably the wrong place to keep the list, unless maybe it's a list of related accounts? (but then using a `static` would be wrong). Side note— When _declaring_ a List it should not pick an implementation: `List<Conta> ListaUser = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @StephenP I will try making a new class just for the purpose of storing the list. But should it work without adding anything else? I cant see how it would be much different because i dont need to label each element inside the list, thats why i didnt do it to begin with. Its a list of accounts, and inside each account there should be the user informations, such as the name, password, acc number, etc. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @WildDracula, that would be a minimal fix to your code.  Or you could just move list of `Conta` objects to your JFrame class to avoid creating extra container classes.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Conta` has it's own copy of `ListaUser` so when you do

```
Conta C = new Conta(...);
C.AddFunc(C);
```

You are adding `C` to *C's own copy* of ListaUser, and each Conta C will contain a List `ListaUser` that has only one element in the list; the C itself. Stated another way, each Conta will have a list with only itself as the list contents; there is no list that contains *all* of the Conta's that you have created.

An *Account* (Conta) should not be the place that maintains the list of accounts your program is keeping. It is the program itself that is concerned with the accounts, so the program has-a list of accounts.

```
public class Cadastrar extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private List<Conta> listaUser = new ArrayList<>();
    private Cadastrar program;

    public Cadastrar() {
        initComponents();
        program = this;
    }
    // etc.
```

Later in the program in `jButtonconfirmarcadastroActionPerformed` when you create a Conta you would add it to the program's list

```
Conta c = new Conta(...);
program.listaUser.add(c);
// or possibly: program.storeConta(c);
```

At some point in your program you might want to show the list, maybe in response to another button-press, which might look something like this, if you were just printing to the console (I'm not going to write code here to display it in a JPanel or anything)

```
// other methods that are in class Cadastrar
List<Conta> getContaList()
{
    return program.listaUser;
}

void listContas()
{
    for (Conta c : program.getContaList()) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Often you might use `this` instead of keeping a separate variable `program`

Notice also that I changed the case of variable names… it is not a hard rule, but is a convention in Java that class names should start with uppercase, like `Conta` but variable names start with lowercase, like `listaUser` instead of `ListaUser`.

I haven't done Swing programming in a long time, but it is (or was?) also common practice to have an *Application* object that is separate from your main `JFrame`, so you might have this sort of arrangement...

```
public class MyApplication
{
    // the Program owns the list, which the JFrame will use
    private static final List<Conta> listaUser = new ArrayList<>();
    // because we pass the list to the application window in `main`
    Cadastrar appWindow;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        // here is where you would do your LookAndFeel initialization,
        // and create an instance of your application's main window
        appWindow = new Cadastrar(listaUser);
        // obviously this sample code is incomplete, just to demonstrate
        // that your Program sets up the environment and creates the
        // main window which the User will interact with.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain it in great detail! I did understand why i shouldnt keep a list of the same type as the class inside said class and the other tips, but unfortunatelly there must be other elements of my code that are making it not work. I followed your instructions and the code looked the same as yours, but when printing (even to the console) it simply doesnt show me anything...The worst part is that i dont get any errors, it opens without any problem. I do have a main window tho, but i dont know if it is relevant to the problem im having

Comment: @WildDracula what I've written is more about design _principles_, and I don't expect my samples would work as written. It seems likely that your program as a whole is too big to debug via Stackoverflow questions, but other specific problems may be good as additional questions here. I encourage you at this point to run in a debugger, put a breakpoint where a newly created Conta is added to a/the list, and inspect what is going on with that list… what object owns it; if there are still several separate copies of the list, etc. Breakpoint where you're printing too & check if it's the same list.